# Returning a single date with max(date)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, maxdate

I have the following query. I want to retrieve a list of unique Object ID's with the value closest to a specified date:

```
INSERT INTO @temp 
(
     [Object ID]
    ,[Waarde]
    ,[Kenmerk]
)

select DISTINCT PME.OBJECTID,
                LEFT(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE,LEN(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE)-2),
                'P3'
FROM PMEOBJECTSCORINGPOINTS PME
LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTSCORINGHISTORY PMEH ON PME.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID = PMEH.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID
INNER JOIN(SELECT OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID, MAX(DATE) DATE
           FROM PMEOBJECTSCORINGHISTORY 
           WHERE DATE < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate())-1, 12, 31)
           GROUP BY OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID) P3 ON PME.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID = P3.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID
                                               AND PMEH.DATE = P3.DATE
                                               AND PME.ATTRIBUTEID = 'Energie-idx' 
                                               AND PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE <> ''

------------------
select * from @temp
order by [Object ID], [Kenmerk] ASC
```

When a certain Object ID only has one known value before 2019-12-31, I get one record in the result set. However, if an Object ID has two (or more) known values before that date, I still get multiple results instead of the value for the date closest to 2019-12-31.

Any pointers on how to get the desired results? Thanks in advance!

(edit: apologies for the bad readibility on the code, thanks for fixing it)

Comment: You could do a `SELECT TOP 1` and add an `ORDER BY whateverdate DESC` to only get the one result.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytical funtion ROW_NUMBER(), if you can sort on a column, Perhaps P3.Date or PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE

```
select Objectid, OBJECTSCORINGVALUE,P3 
from(   
select          PME.OBJECTID,
                LEFT(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE,LEN(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE)-2) OBJECTSCORINGVALUE,
                'P3' Pcol,P3.Date

                row_number() over (partition by PME.OBJECTID, LEFT(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE,LEN(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE)-2) order by P3.Date DESC) rn
FROM PMEOBJECTSCORINGPOINTS PME
LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTSCORINGHISTORY PMEH ON PME.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID = PMEH.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID
INNER JOIN(SELECT OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID, MAX(DATE) DATE
           FROM PMEOBJECTSCORINGHISTORY 
           WHERE DATE < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate())-1, 12, 31)
           GROUP BY OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID) P3 ON PME.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID = P3.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID
                                               AND PMEH.DATE = P3.DATE
                                               AND PME.ATTRIBUTEID = 'Energie-idx' 
                                               AND PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE <> ''
   ) where rn=1
```

Here I order the replies with P3.Date, and return only the one with the highest value.

It is guaranteed to only return one row, however you have to be sure about your data to be sure that it is deterministic

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Turned out I did an incorrect join (wrong level of granularity). I should have done it on OBJECTID instead of OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID. The result was that the max(date) was returned for OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID instead of on the level of OBJECTID.

This is the correct query:

```
INSERT INTO @temp 
(
     [Object ID]
    ,[Waarde]
    ,[Kenmerk]
)

select          PME.OBJECTID,
                LEFT(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE,LEN(PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE)-2),
                'P3'
FROM PMEOBJECTSCORINGPOINTS PME
LEFT JOIN PMEOBJECTSCORINGHISTORY PMEH ON PME.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID = PMEH.OBJECTSCORINGHISTORYID
INNER JOIN(SELECT OBJECTID, MAX(DATE) DATE
           FROM PMEOBJECTSCORINGHISTORY 
           WHERE DATE < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate())-1, 12, 31)
           GROUP BY OBJECTID) P3 ON PME.OBJECTID = P3.OBJECTID
                                               AND PMEH.DATE = P3.DATE
                                               AND PME.ATTRIBUTEID = 'Energie-idx' 
                                               AND PME.OBJECTSCORINGVALUE <> ''
```